# WMS GetFeatureInfo and Google maps api V3

Tags: google-maps, wms, getfeatureinfo

Is there a way to request GetFeatureInfo from a WMS service with the Google maps api v3?

Comment: To clarify, do you want to use your own mapping server with Google Maps as the base layer?

Comment: No, using google maps layers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/doc/) API you can use GetFeatureInfo from a WMS service

But Google Maps API (v3) you cannot add a WMS service - only KML is supported

[image]

Example
http://www.gisdoctor.com/v3/openlayers_wms.html

Comment: Clarification, WMS is supported in Google Maps V3, see [link](http://www.gisdoctor.com/v3/v3_wms.html). You probably meant that GetFeatureInfo is available with Openlayers.

Answer (score 2):

Now, We can add WMS service with google map api v3. You can access here
https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-api-with-wms-overlay/source/browse/